# ReactJS Browserify and Babel

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs

Sorry if this sound a very basic question but I am new to gulp and browserify. I have a gulp task file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('bundle', function(){
    return browserify({
        extensions: ['js', 'jsx'],
        entries: 'assets/js/src/main.js'
    })
        .transform(babelify.configure({
            ignore: /(bower_components)|(node_modules)/
        }))
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function(err){
            console.log('Error : ' + err.message);
        })
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/'));
});

// Watch JS/JSX and Sass files
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('assets/js/src/**/*.{js,jsx}', ['bundle']);
});
```

Here I want to transpile my code to ES2015 but I am not sure what assets/src/main.js file in browserify task should have. My question would be, is main.js just an entry point for browserify? If yes then what should it have?

Answer (score 0):

`entries` would be the entry point of your react application so where reactDOM render is done and where your app is declared, for example it can contain:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Comment: I made routers.jsx to by entry point, but it was able to parse react components, such as <Header /> etc.